# How to make flexbox items equal height and/or start at the same point

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I'm creating flexbox cards to display three elements. A title, an `<hr>` and a paragraph. The title text length varies, which creates a varying height.

I'd like to have all the titles have the same height, so that each card is uniform. If this is not possible, I would like the paragraphs to be horizontally aligned on each card.

I've tried giving the title a `flex: 1` property to push the paragraph down, but it creates too much space.

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJgJYd) and demo:

```css
  body {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
  h2,
  p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
  h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  }
  /*******************************************************/
  .cards {
    display: flex;
  }
  .card {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .card-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  }
  .card-paragraph {
    text-align: center;
  }
  hr {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
  }
  /*******************************************************/
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title">
        Title one IS LONGER THAN TITLE TWO
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-paragraph">  
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title">
        TITLE TWO
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-paragraph">  
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

**What I want**:

[image]

**What is happening**:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aligning *adjacent flexbox* containers may not be possible - CSS Grid might be a good choice:

- use `display: contents` on the `card` or remove the wrapper altogether
- use a 2-column grid and place the `card-title` to the first row using `grid-row: 1`
- place the `card-paragraph` to the thrid row using `grid-row: 3` and place the `hr` in between using `grid-row: 2`.

See demo below:

```css
body {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.cards {
  /* display: flex; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.card {
  /* border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  width: 50%;*/
  display: contents; /* added */
}

.card-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin: 0 0 25px 0;*/
  grid-row: 1; /* added */
  border: 1px solid;  /* added */
}

.card-paragraph {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 3; /* added */
  border: 1px solid;  /* added */
}

hr {
  height: 3px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  background: #333;
  margin: 0; /* added */
  grid-row: 2; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title">
        Title one IS LONGER THAN TITLE TWO
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-paragraph">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title">
        TITLE TWO
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-paragraph">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: How supported is the use of display: grid? Your answer does my solve my problem nicely, however the HR is at the bottom of the card container? EDIT: I changed the grid-row property to 3 instead of 2

Comment: @Rich fixed the `hr`... grid is supported in modern browsers, you don't have in it IE... https://caniuse.com/#search=css-grid

Comment: Ok. Kind of needed IE, but still a good solution. No way to align content like that just using flex at all?

Comment: and support for `display: contents` - https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20contents

Comment: @Rich no, you can't align *flex items* in *adjacent flexboxes*.... see [another discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272962/alignment-of-content-vertically-in-adjacent-flexbox-containers/55291645#55291645) :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest CSS Grid for something like this:

```css
body {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}


/*******************************************************/

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: auto;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid;
  grid-row: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.card-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.card-paragraph {
  text-align: center;
}

hr {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
}


/*******************************************************/
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title">
        Title one IS LONGER THAN TITLE TWO Title one IS LONGER THAN TITLE TWO Title one IS LONGER THAN TITLE TWO
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-paragraph">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title">
        TITLE TWO
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-paragraph">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Any reason why the colums are huge?

Comment: It's because of the bottom margin of `25px` in `.card-title`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with flexbox only by setting height of the title:

    `.card-title {
      ...
      height: 50px;
    }`

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBRMoj)

Comment: But then if I have a long title that surpasses 50px in height, the text will overflow from the container. Not a solution.