# Align the top of the footers bootstrap card deck

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-cards

I'm using bootstrap 4 to display cards. All is working as expected. The issue I have is that if one of the footers has more content than the others, the footer is raised to accommodate this. Is there a way of the footer pushing the content down and keeping the tops aligned?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6uv9a30n/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Current Output:
[image]

Desired Output:
[image]

Comment: If you're not putting that data dynamically, then you can preset the footer with a fixed height shared across the small-text part

Comment: @eric thanks for the suggestion but the content is dynamically generated

Comment: Did you find a working solution? If not my approach to this would be to make small-text part scrollable with the `overflow: scroll;` property. This would also prevent the card from looking funny with too much whitespace when the data of one card increases way too much.

Comment: Not w/o using a defined footer height. Flexbox children aren't aware of each others content. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272962/alignment-of-content-vertically-in-adjacent-flexbox-containers

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be sound cheap but you can use another `small` HTML tag having `css` property `transparent` color so that it will always remain on top not matter how much text you add.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        <small style="color: transparent;">Text not going to show</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago Last updated 3 mins ago</small>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        <small style="color: transparent;">Text not going to show</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the only issue with this is that it would apply to all cards. There will be multiple rows, so i'd only want that row to be effected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `flex` CSS property on `card-body` and `card-footer`.

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

/* Customize Bootstrap card */
.card-deck .card-body { 
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

/* fix footer height */
.card-footer { 
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer equal">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was really hoping this fixed it as it looked close. The issue is that they do not line up when the card-body content is different http://jsfiddle.net/ae9hp8ok/